# QGIS 3.22.16 using a unique color for each category

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, color-ramp, categorized-renderer

I am using QGIS 3.22.16. I am trying to symbolize multiple land owners using the categorize option. However, the random selection brings similar color for different landowner. I tried to use different ramps option. It still have the same issue. Does QGIS have an algorithm or tool to distribute unique colors to each category?

[image]

Comment: If you have more than 8-12 unique values, it won't be possible to randomly choose colors and get completely distinct colors, and that's before ADA guidelines kick in to address colorblindness.

Comment: You could consider using fill patterns to start differentiating categories instead of just colours.